# Hide and Collapse menu using Vaadin

Tags: vaadin

Does any one know about how to create hide and collapse content using vaadin api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it by using TabSheet functionality of vaadin.I created two tabs '+' and '-' whenever user clicks on '-' Tab It am setting the TabSheet height to 100% and whenever the  user clicks on the '+' Tab I am setting the height of the TabSheet to 20% (visible height of the tabsheet) so whatever the content in the TabSheet will be hided in user perspective.

```
     // Create an empty tab sheet.
    TabSheet tabsheet = new TabSheet();


    // Defining Vertical Layout for Tab 1 content
    final VerticalLayout verLayout1 = new VerticalLayout();


       // Tab 2 content
    VerticalLayout verLayout2 = new VerticalLayout();
    verLayout2.setSizeUndefined();
    verLayout2.setMargin(true);

    tabsheet.addTab(verLayout1, "+", null);
    tabsheet.addTab(verLayout2, "-", null);
    tabsheet.addListener(listenerForTab());




      /**
   * Method to handle tab sheet hide/show event
   * 
   * @return TabSheet.SelectedTabChangeListener
   */
  public TabSheet.SelectedTabChangeListener listenerForTab() {
    _logger.info("Entering in to tabChangeListener of WizardUtil");
    // Instance of TabSheet.SelectedTabChangeListener
    TabSheet.SelectedTabChangeListener listener = new TabSheet.SelectedTabChangeListener() {
      public void selectedTabChange(SelectedTabChangeEvent event) {
        TabSheet tabsheet = event.getTabSheet();
        Tab tab = tabsheet.getTab(tabsheet.getSelectedTab());
        // Tab content displayed on setting height to the tab sheet
        if(tab.getCaption().equals("+")) {
          tabsheet.setHeight("100%");
        } else {
          tabsheet.setHeight("33px");
        }
      }
    };
    _logger.info("Exiting from tabChangeListener of WizardUtil");
    return listener;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

All components inherit the setVisible() method which can trigger visibility on and off. This means all components and component containers at least. This happens without animations, though. 
If you like some animations, you have to rely to add-ons, e.g. Henrik Paul's [Drawer](http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/drawer) does some kind of hide and show animations.

Is this what you were thinking about?